# TensorFlow2.1: Opened Dynamic Library: libcuda.so.1

Tags: python, tensorflow

The error of Tensorflow 2.1 appears by depending on the user permission of Python.

For example without `sudo`,

```
$ python
>>> import tensorflow
[TIME]: W tensorflow/stream_executor/...] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6' ...
>>> tensorflow.config.list_physical_devices()
[TIME]: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loaer.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
```

Then, the another error would appears,

```
[TIME]: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN: unknown error
```

When I work on `sudo` authorization,

```
$ sudo python
>>> import tensorflow
[TIME]: W tensorflow/stream_executor/...] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6' ...
>>> tensorflow.config.list_physical_devices()
[TIME]: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loaer.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[TIME]: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:351] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
```

Tensorflow 2.1 would not able to find `libcuda.so.1` and It would get an error `UNKNOWN ERROR (303)`

Why does it load the dynamic library when it don't have `sudo` permission? Also, what steps should be taken to resolve this `UNKNOWN ERROR(303)`?

Comment: I think you have a wrong or corrupted version of CUDA installed. Try reinstalling the correct version. You can find the matching versions here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source

Comment: `cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt` => `CUDA Version 10.1.243`, `cat /usr/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2` => `CUDNN_MAJOR 7 CUDNN_MINOR 6 ...`, `gcc -V` => `gcc version 7.5.0`. I think they seems compatible one another in TensorFlow 2.1.

Comment: I faced similar issue when I restart the system, at very first instance it throws this error. I don't think it is cuda compatibility issue because CUDA 10.1 works with tensorflow 2.1. Please, Don't know how and why - I have read through some forums and even they said not to ask why. Put these lines at the start
```
import tensorflow as tf
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)
```
it might help

Comment: @vasista thanks for your response, but there is no content in gpus. so, It occurs `IndexError: list index out of range`. I think tensorflow can not detect `tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices`

Comment: I have made a symbolic link by `sudo ln -f -s /usr/local/cuda/compat/libcuda.so.418.39 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1`, then the error msg of `Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'` would disapper. But `UNKNOWN ERROR(303)` still appears. How can I resolve it?

Comment: @GiYeonShin Will the program fails with this message? or it just throws as warning and program continue to run?

Comment: @GiYeonShin Read through this https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37689

If it continues to run after throwing the above message. Before tf1 has two separate libraries for CPU and GPU. Now in tf2 it always checks for GPU and intialises these errors. That thread demonstrates that

Comment: The program continues to run without gpu. But I want that the program would run with GPU. I don't know why `nvidia-smi` detects GPU, but TF2.1 can not detect GPU. This problem is also found in PyTorch. `torch.cuda.is_available()` always throws `False`.